# Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a chatting application using **Firebase**.

**for some time i'm getting this error** `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDate' was called on null.`

Getting error when converting `Timestamp` to `DateTime` using `toDate()`.

**GIVES ERROR FOR SOME TIME AND THEN ERROR DISAPPEARS.**

**PLEASE CONSIDER THIS GIF**.

[image: THIS]

**HERE IS FIRESTORE DATATYPE AS** `TimeStamp`.

[image]

**SOURCE CODE**

```
class ChatMessageModel {
  bool isSentByMe;
  String msg = '';

  ///SERVER TIME
  Timestamp time;
  DateTime localTime;
  String timeStamp;
  String fromUid;
  String toUid;

  ChatMessageModel._();

  ChatMessageModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    this.isSentByMe =
        snapshot.data['from'] == LoginBloc.instance.firebaseUser.uid;
    this.msg = snapshot.data['msg'];
    this.timeStamp = snapshot.data['time'].toString();
    this.time = snapshot.data['time'];
    this.fromUid = snapshot.data['from'];
    this.toUid = snapshot.data['to'];
    this.localTime = this.time.toDate(); //ERROR
  }
}
```

**THANKS IN ADVANCE.**

Comment: try `snapshot.data['time'].toDate`

Comment: tried. nothing changed.

Comment: It seems that there is bug in `firestore` api. `StreamBuilder`'s builder method called 2 times first with null value of `timestamp` and second with not-null values.

Comment: The Angela's Flutter training course at Udemy? I am having exactly the same error with the Flash Chat app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to convert `time` to `Date` before it is fetched, a short workaround would be initializing your `time` variable with current time before server's value loads:

```
  Timestamp time = new Timestamp( new Date(2019,3,4) );
```

another solution would be to use an `async` method to `await` the value from the server before converting it, which you can't afford given that you want to use it in instant messeging.More can be found in the official Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) and the android developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html).

Note that the above code will result in a `Timestamp` pointing to midnight, but shouldn't be an issue since it is a brief placeholder compared to Firebase response speed.

Comment: `DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch` can't be converted to Timestamp.

Comment: I corrected the mistake, hope it solves your problem

Comment: i'm listening to the firebase stream and till i know that streams only updates value when some value changes in that stream. So the data must be loaded in the form of snapshot.

Answer (score 4):

It is showing error because at the calling time of this.time,
this.time getting null. So toDate() function can't be able to applying on null

**Try changing :**
`this.localTime = this.time.toDate();`

**To :**

```
this.localTime = this.time == null ? DateTime.now()
    : this.time.toDate();
```

OR You can use like this :

```
String stringtime = widget.time == null
        ? DateTime.now().toString()
        : widget.time.toDate().toString();
    // stringtime = widget.time.toDate().toString();
    DateTime date = DateTime.parse(stringtime);
    String clocktime = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(date);
```

**Hope it helps, worked for me :)**

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
this.localTime = this.time.toDate();
```

to

```
this.localTime = this.time.toDate()==null?DateTime().now():this.time.toDate();
```

for better readability save `this.time.toDate()` in a variable.Hope it helps,worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
ds['time'] == null? Text(DateTime.now().toString())
  : Text(
   DateFormat("hh:mm a").format(
   ds['time'].toDate(),
 ),
),
```